# What're the point of internal networking within the same company if nowadays people change jobs so frequently?

Tags: networking

People say network to get a job. However...

What're the point of internal networking within the same company if nowadays people change jobs so frequently? Especially compensation for job hopping is way better than staying within the same company, the incentive for people to stay long in same company is low. So basically internal networking serves minimum use of boosting compensations?

At the same time, braindrain becomes a norm, for those you networked yesterday may as well gone tomorrow. And I see many people just cut off from all form of communication with the ex-colleagues once they leave the company. This makes the original effort of internal networking go into vain.

Thus, is internal networking still useful? If yes, how?

Comment: The entire point of networking to get a job is those people going into other companies where they could help get you on, right?  It’d be more useless if they all stayed in your old company, right?  Think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thus, is internal networking still useful? If yes, how?

X years from now when you are looking to leave, those people you met today may be the reference you need in their new company. Most of the people I worked with 10 years ago aren't  still with the same company, but they are spread across a dozen companies.

I got my most recent job because somebody knew me 3 jobs ago. We didn't even work together, but a common person meant we had heard of each other. A few jobs before that something similar happened.

Sometimes those previous connection contact you when you aren't looking. Sometimes you reach out to them when you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

> if nowadays people change jobs so frequently?

I think your question is based on too broad a premise. Job hopping is indeed very common for junior people in certain industries. However, it gets rarer as people rise through the ranks.

Job hopping only makes sense of what you are doing is mostly a commodity. The highest job hopping rates are in the service industry. If you are senior leader in a very technical field, it often takes months or even years to fully come up to speed, so job hopping doesn't really make a lot of sense.

> At the same time, braindrain becomes a norm,

Not really. The brains that are draining are typically not the ones you actually care about. Most companies have retention and incentive plans for those employees that really want to keep.

> And I see many people just cut off from all form of communication with the ex-colleagues once they leave the company.

That's odd and certainly hasn't happened to me. I have great relationships with many people I have worked with before.

> What're the point of internal networking

I network for a variety of reasons: a) it's fun, b) network has helped me a lot in finding job opportunities and clients, c) I have access to experts that I can ask for advise or help, etc.